# dynamically change the calculation from the text box using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have scenario here, input and display page are generated dynamically from php code.
enter code here

```
<div>Aeroplane</div>
   <input id="Item556" type='number' onchange="funCal('Item556', this.value, 'Aeroplane')">
   <input class="disp" name="Item556" type="text" disabled>

  <div>Plane</div>
  <input id="Item557" type='number' onchange="funCal('Item557', this.value, 'Plane')">
  <input class="disp" name="Item557"  type="text" disabled>

  <div>Bikes</div>
  <input id="Item558" type='number' onchange="funCal('Item558', this.value, 'Bikes')">
  <input class="disp" name="Item558" type="text" disabled >

  <div>Cars</div>
  <input id="Item559" type='number' onchange="funCal('Item559', this.value, 'Cars')">
  <input class="disp" name="Item559"  type="text" disabled >
```

Ajax is :

```
function funCal(ID, value, name){
    var ID1 = ID;   var value1 = value; var name1 = name;
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"calculate.php",
                    data: "id="+ID1+"&value="+value1,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){
                    <span>pound;+ data.output +</span>

//added similar to self.next().val(data.output); and tweak around it to work.
updateTotal();
                            }
                    });     
            };
);

function updateTotal() {
var total = 0;

$("input.disp").each(function() {
    getPrices = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ''));
    total += getPrices;
});

$("span#total").html("&pound;" + total.toFixed(2)).digits();
```

}

1 . What I want to achieve is when value is entered in input box the corresponding box (with class "disp" box should display the calculated value.)
ex, the input id with Item559 should display after the ajax success value on input box with name"Item559".
Any experts advice will be valuable and much appreciated , because I am very new to ajax and php.---I got the answer for the first as Bhadra suggested below
2 . How do I add-up or sum the total value from the input.disp box? Suggestion or recommendation much appreciated Please!
Thanks in advance

Comment: A few comments: you have html code in your success function, that will give an error, furthermore, you have many closing `div` tags that were never opened, the `id` for any element should always be unique, and you now have 4 inputs with the `id` set to `"disp"`, and those inputs also have no type defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function updateTotal() {
var total = 0;

$(".disp").each(function() {
    var getPrices = parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '').replace('pound;',''),10);
    total += getPrices;
});

$("span#total").html("&pound;" + total.toFixed(2)).digits();

}
```

Comment: better check what `this` is within ajax callback

Comment: changed it to self.now it should nt be a problem

Comment: Sorry Bahdra! I didn't get it. what is the use of self.next().

Comment: self.next() refers to next element to 'self'. self is the present '.numberclass' element undergoing change, and we want to replace the next '.disp' element value with the new value from ajax success

Comment: Sorry Bahdra! I didn't get it. what is the meaning of self.next() ? inside success function code. The scenario code above is working condition. Just want to display the calculated value returned "after ajax success"  next to the Kg/data Entered respectively.

Comment: the code exactly does that .it gives the value which is returned from jax to the next element .var self=$(this); self is the input elemnt in which u have typed

Comment: Hey Bhadra! How to I get total sum of  the all update data from the "self.next().val('pound;'+ data.output);" or the display updated input box.? Any idea!